# Custom styled dropdown using Spring MVC/Forms

Tags: jquery, css, jsp, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I am filling a dropdown in a form using the following.

```
<div class="state">
  <label for="state">state</label>
  <form:select path="state" id="state" required="true">
    <form:option value="" />
    <form:options items="${stateOptions}" itemLabel="value" />
  </form:select>
</div>
```

This works fine but I have trouble styling it. I am looking for a polyfil or jquery lib that will allow me to create styled dropdowns without having to switch to an unordered list preferably. If that is impossible what is the best way with JSP to handle this using Twitter Bootstrap or one of the other UL based solutions and still have Spring recognize the value.

**Par**

Works fine on chrome but looks REALLY bad on IE/FF

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Bootstrap. it's a css framework, which has nice out-of-the-box components and also supports responsive design (changing layout based on device screen size, and thus supporting mobile)

Below is a link to their basic form elements styling

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

If you'd like to learn it, I found the next tutorial to be a good starting point (You can do it in less than an hour if you already have a way with html/css)

http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-twitter-bootstrap-3/

Also, there are many templates who are based on bootstrap and have their sets of components. You can have a look [here](https://wrapbootstrap.com/)

Comment: Again per my previous post I would like to avoid changing my code to an unordered list (which bootstrap requires)

Comment: Bootstrap 3 does not require you to chage your code to <ul>, it applies style to the <select> itself. Take a look at the links I gave you.

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't realize that

Comment: It's ok, I hope you found what you're looking for :)